# How does mercurial treat ignored files inside a jar file?

Tags: mercurial

e.g: I've add into `.hgignore` file a rule to ignore `.class` files. But i'd like Mercurial to track some jar files which contain `.class` files of library software. It will see the jar's file date signature only or it'll go through the class files inside?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .jar is technically just a zip archive, and therefore Mercurial sees it as a single binary file.